# Why Failed to open file error is happening in this line

Tags: android, file

Error :  E/FileSource: Failed to open file 'android.resource:/com.android.grafika/2130968577'. (No such file or directory)

```
String vidAddress = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.b_right;
Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
File sliders = new File(vidUri.toString());
Log.d("File",sliders.toString());
```

How to fix it? and what is the root cause? I mean what is wrong with this code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean what is wrong with this code snippet?

First, passing the string representation of a `Uri` to the `File` constructor will never work. A `Uri` has a scheme; the `File` constructor will not know what to do with the scheme.

Second, the `android.resource` scheme is for an Android resource. While resources are files on your developer machine, they are *not* files on the Android device and cannot be represented by a `File` object.

> How to fix it?

Do not attempt to access a resource via a `File` object.

For example, you can [call `openRawResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29) on a `Resources` object to get an `InputStream` on your raw resource, given the resource ID.

Comment: But File has a constructor with File(URI uri) [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) . So how does that work @CommonsWare ?

Comment: @Bee: That's `java.net.URI`, not `android.net.Uri`. I am not aware that `File` is going to expect and remove a scheme from the `File(String)` constructor. Moreover, as I point out in my answer, the resource is not a file anyway. So, even if `File(String)` does see a scheme, removes it, and attempts to use the rest as a filesystem path, that code will fail for you too, because **there is no file**, let alone at that location.

Comment: Is there any w\ay that I can have it as file? may not how I tried but in any other way to have it as file? @CommonsWare

Comment: @Bee: You would have to copy the data from the `InputStream` that you get from the raw resource to an `OutputStream` pointing to some file, then use that file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the file path you constructed does not exist.

To open raw resources, use [openRawResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29).  For example:

```
InputStream stream = getContext().getResources().openRawResource( R.raw.b_right );
```

Comment: But File has a constructor with File(URI uri) [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) . So how does that work @dsh ?

Comment: a) you didn't call that constructor; you called vidUri.toString() and thus called File(String path).  b) Read the documentation: `uri needs to be an absolute and hierarchical Unified Resource Identifier with file scheme and non-empty path component, but with undefined authority, query or fragment components.`  Your URI does not meet these requirements.  Use `openRawResources()` to open a raw resource.

Comment: vidUri.getpath() also do the same. Is there any way I can costruct it the uri as file? May be from any other location. I have a mp4 and I want it as file actually. It will help me. @dsh

Comment: Thank you . I can not accept 2 answer although they both are correct. so as 1st one I am accepting the other answer and giving a up to your answer as they both are basically same . @dsh

Comment: Yes, we both gave the same recommendation at the same time. Just a note: [`URI.getPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getPath--) gives you the path *component of the URI* (text which you yourself computed) but does not make a file exist on the local filesystem. That is why it did not work for you either.

Answer (score 0):

final String uriPath="android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/texivedio";